PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pq.so'
Full error
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pq.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/pq.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/pq.so: undefined symbol: php_resource_factory_handle_ctor), /usr/lib/php/20230831/pq.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/pq.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

I am unsure what is installed that requires this and I have tried to look around for what pq.so is for but have been unable to find out what needs to be installed or uninstalled.
I get this when running a cli command for xenforo.
/usr/bin/php /var/www/forum/cmd.php --quiet xf:run-jobs

Any insight on what I need to install or uninstall to get rid of this error message. I dont believe its impacting system operations at the moment.

If the answer works, it works and you can accept it.  If you say that the error persists, then it hasn't worked and future readers shouldn't be misled by a green tick.
